# Python3 Bytes encoding

Tags: python, string, byte, decode, encode

I am working with python3 and I have a problem with the representation of an object.
It is the result of `subprocess.Open().communicate()[0]`, which is a bytes-array but when I pass it to another function, python interprets it as a string, which is not.
This is the array that i have:

> b'N\x00e\x00l\x00
>   \x00s\x00o\x00t\x00t\x00o\x00s\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00a\x00
>   \x00W\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00 \x00p\x00e\x00r\x00
>   \x00L\x00i\x00n\x00u\x00x\x00 \x00n\x00o\x00n\x00
>   \x00s\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00
>   \x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00
>   \x00d\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00b\x00u\x00z\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00i\x00.\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00L\x00e\x00
>   \x00d\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00b\x00u\x00z\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00i\x00
>   \x00p\x00o\x00s\x00s\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00
>   \x00e\x00s\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00
>   \x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00
>   \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00
>   \x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00
>   \x00S\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00:\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00h\x00t\x00t\x00p\x00s\x00:\x00/\x00/\x00a\x00k\x00a\x00.\x00m\x00s\x00/\x00w\x00s\x00l\x00s\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00'

Which is in ASCII encode, right?

My question is how can I encode it to see the right bytes values?
Or is there at least a way to pass it to the other function without it been recognised as a string, which is not?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/2375207 helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can decode it with `.decode('utf-8')`
To remove the null bytes use `.replace(b'\x00', b'')`

```
subprocessoutput = b'N\x00e\x00l\x00 \x00s\x00o\x00t\x00t\x00o\x00s\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00a\x00 \x00W\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00 \x00p\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00L\x00i\x00n\x00u\x00x\x00 \x00n\x00o\x00n\x00 \x00s\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00b\x00u\x00z\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00i\x00.\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00L\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00b\x00u\x00z\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00i\x00 \x00p\x00o\x00s\x00s\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00 \x00e\x00s\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00 \x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00 \x00S\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00:\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00h\x00t\x00t\x00p\x00s\x00:\x00/\x00/\x00a\x00k\x00a\x00.\x00m\x00s\x00/\x00w\x00s\x00l\x00s\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00'

print(subprocessoutput.replace(b'\x00', b'').decode('utf-8'))
```

edit:
the following creates a list with the ascii numbers in decimal:

```
ascii = [ord(x) for x in subprocessoutput.decode('utf-8')]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but the problem is still here. I've checked online and really the encoding of this ASCII string is a series of numbers, exactly what i need, but i cannot seem to obtain it on python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this isn't UTF-8, it's UTF-16.

```
#!/bin/python3

var = b'N\x00e\x00l\x00 \x00s\x00o\x00t\x00t\x00o\x00s\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00a\x00 \x00W\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00 \x00p\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00L\x00i\x00n\x00u\x00x\x00 \x00n\x00o\x00n\x00 \x00s\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00b\x00u\x00z\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00i\x00.\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00L\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00b\x00u\x00z\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00i\x00 \x00p\x00o\x00s\x00s\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00 \x00e\x00s\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00 \x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00 \x00S\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00:\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00h\x00t\x00t\x00p\x00s\x00:\x00/\x00/\x00a\x00k\x00a\x00.\x00m\x00s\x00/\x00w\x00s\x00l\x00s\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00'

foo = str(var, 'utf-16')

print(foo)
```

This yields

> Nel sottosistema Windows per Linux non sono installate distribuzioni.
>   Le distribuzioni possono essere installate visitando Microsoft Store:
>   https://aka.ms/wslstore